# Firebase email template doesnt allow me. I cant change it

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

How can i change the firebase email verification interface. firebase doesnt allow me. is there any other way if i can't change it from firebase site ?

[image: firebase mail template]